# Python palindrome program w/o string functions

Tags: python, string, palindrome

I'm a beginner in Python. I've written palindrome programs without using string functions.

*Question 1:* Why does the 1st logic not give me the desired output? Correct me if I'm wrong.

*Question 2:* In the 2nd program if I skip `i += 1` in if statement it should give me the correct result as the `for` loop automatically increments value of `i`. Rather it gives me correct output only if I include that statement or else not. What may be the reason for this?

*Logic 1:*

```
n = input("eNTER  STRING\n")
length = int(len(n))
n = str(n)

for i in range(0, int(length/2+1)):
   if n[i] != n[-i - 1]:
      break

if i < int(length/2 + 1):
   print("not")
else:
   print("yes")
```

*Logic 2:*

```
n = input("ENTER  STRING\n")
length = int(len(n))

for i in range(0, int(length/2 + 1)):
   if n[i] == n[-i - 1]:
      i += 1
   else:
      break

if i < (length / 2):
   print("not")
else:
   print("yes")
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: it would be so much easier if you didn't write monolithic code... e.g.: `return false`.

Comment: I couldn't handle the formatting so I made it look acceptable

Comment: @Pranay Binju Please check an answer as correct answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Logic 1, try `if i<int(length/2):` instead of `if i<int((length/2+1)):`

In Logic 2, even removing `i+=1` gives the correct result:

```
if n[i] == n[-i-1]:
    pass
else:
    break
```

You can also use the following code for the same:

```
def reverse(text):
    if len(text) <= 1:
        return text
    return reverse(text[1:]) + text[0]

n = input("ENTER  STRING\n")
if n==reverse(n):
    print ("It's a palindrome")
else:
    print ("It's not a palindrome")
```

Comment: Adding pass instead of i+=1 is also not giving desirable o/p..just tried it

Comment: n=input("ENTER  STRING\n")
length=int(len(n))

for i in range(0,int(length/2+1)):
 if n[i] == n[-i-1]:
     pass
 else:
      break
if i<(length/2):
   print ("not")
else:
   print ("yes")

Comment: no I haven't. it still gives me the correct output. check with "aabaa".

Answer (score 3):

Solution to first logic is:

```
n = raw_input("eNTER  STRING\n")           
length = len(n)           
for i in range(0, (length/2)+1):
    if n[i] != n[-i - 1]:           
        break           

if i < int(length/2):  #Not length/2 + 1, as index starts at 0 and not 1. 
   print("not")
else:
   print("yes")
```

In the second logic, you just need to see if there is any character from left and right side that is NOT same. So you can change your code like this :-

```
n = raw_input("ENTER  STRING\n")
length = len(n)

for i in range(0, int(length/2 + 1)):
    if n[i] is not n[-i - 1]:      #change logic here.
        break

if i < (length / 2):
   print("not")
else:
   print("yes")
```

Comment: You should use `!=` rather than `is not` to test inequality of strings, since `is` tests for object identity. Your code works in this case, but it won't in other situations, eg `a='AB';b='A';b=b+'B';print a==b, a is b`

Answer (score 2):

```
while True:
    x=input("Enter a string: ")
    if x==x[::-1]:
        print ("It's a palindrom")
    else:
        print ("It's not a palindrom")
```

Here is a quick test for a word is palindrom or not. Simple as you see.You can check the input for it's building by only letters. Its just a point for making an idea on you.

> And a little 'security' for program:

```
while True:
    x=input("Enter a string: ")
    if x.isalpha():#checking input has only strings
        if x==x[::-1]:
            print ("It's a palindrom")
        else:
            print ("It's not a palindrom")
    else:
        print ("We allow only strings.")
```

So only alphabetic characters will process.No numbers,symbols etc.

Answer (score 0):

Off by one errors in your comparisons. In the first piece of logic, you say, if the first index of the word where the character is not equal to its "mirrored" one is less than len(word)/2 +1 then its not a palindrome.

So lets take aboba (indices: 0,1,2,3,4)

The first index where the character is not equal to its mirrored one is 2 (the character 'o') (we start from zero)
Is 2<(5/2)+1 or 2<2+1 2<3 ?
Yes, then your logic says its not a palindrome, even though it clearly is.

It is quite confusing also to test for the truth of a statement and then output "not".. it's a habit new programmers shouldn't get into and I'd wager it's part of why you have problems finding the mistake yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way.

```
def PAL(S):
    return S== ''.join(reversed(S))

>>> PAL('ABABA')
True
>>> PAL('ABAA')
False
```

Answer (score 0):

1) The logic is fine - the problem is the `if` statement at the end. `range(0, int(length/2 + 1))` contains all numbers from `0` to `length/2` - that's why checking `if i < int(length/2 + 1)` will *always* return `True`.

2) This works even if you remove `i += 1`.

---

You could have easily avoided making these little mistakes by getting rid of the second `if` statement:

```
n = input("eNTER  STRING\n")
length = len(n)

for i in range(0, length/2+1):
   if n[i] != n[-i - 1]:
      print("not")
      break
else:
   print("yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=raw_input("eNTER  STRING\n")
b=a[::-1]
if b==a:
  print "True"
else:
  print "false"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string=raw_input("Enter the String:")
l=len(string)
flag=0

for i in range(l/2):
    if string[i]!=string[l-i-1]:
        flag=1
        break

if flag==1:
    print "Not Palindrome"
else:
    print "Palindrome"
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

A one-line solution for this question is;

```
print(["String is a palindrome" if s == s[::-1] else "String is NOT a palindrome"])
```

Usage;

```
s = input("Input something: ")
print(["String is a palindrome" if s == s[::-1] else "String is NOT a palindrome"])
```